# Fastest way to determine dynamic subset of array and check if condition exists

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement the following equation in Python to flag outliers in financial tick data:

[image: equation]

Basically, I'm wondering what's the fastest way to determine the subset of elements needed to check if a condition is met.  The following is an excerpt from the white paper to help explain:

"The neighborhood of observations is always chosen so that a given observation is compared with observations belonging to the same trading day. That is, the neighborhood of the first observation of day are the first k ticks of the day, the neighborhood of the last observation of the day are the last k ticks of the day, the neighborhood of a generic transaction in the middle of the day is made by approximately the first preceding k/2 ticks and the following k/2 ones, and so on. The idea behind the algorithm is to assess the validity of an observation on the basis of its relative distance from a neighborhood of most close valid observations."

I've implemented the following code which works but it's not the most pythonic and would like to avoid looping thru each element in the array if possible.

```
    for dt, by_day in df.groupby(df.date.dt.floor('d')):
        k, y = 250, 3
        px_arr = by_day.price.values

        for i, px in enumerate(px_arr):

            if i <= k:
                neighborhood = px_arr[:k]
            elif len(px_arr) - i <= k:
                neighborhood = px_arr[-k:]
            else:
                neighborhood = px_arr[int(i/2):int(i/2) + k]

            if not abs(px - neighborhood.mean()) < (3 * neighborhood.std() + y):
                log.info(f'Outlier detected! Symbol: {symbol}, Price: {px}, Date {by_day.iloc[i].date}')
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Numpy Masls are what you're looking for: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.html

Comment: I would check out the sliding window view function. https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html. then you can compute mean and std of each window in one call

Comment: @bidout This might be on the right track, but how would you map each price in px_arr to its corresponding window (row) in the sliding array?

Comment: @user23429081 you can use the zip function

Answer (score 1):

This is a pair of somewhat expensive calculations:

```
    if not abs(px - neighborhood.mean()) < (3 * neighborhood.std() + y):
```

That is, we do O(k × n) work rather than O(n),
given `n` price values per day, and k << n.

To cheaply compute a rolling mean we
increment a sum by the price value at leading edge, and
decrement that sum by price value at trailing edge.
Similarly for
[rolling standard deviation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.std.html),
which also tracks squared terms.

This is applicable to the current technique,
and also to Bollinger bands.

Compute

```
    m = neighborhood.rolling(k).mean()
    s = neighborhood.rolling(k).std()
    ...
        delta = abs(px - m[i]) - (3 * s[i] + y)
```

This *will* generate some NaNs on either end,
so you may find it convenient to tack on `k` zeros to the ends.
Or better, `k` copies of first and last price value.

Positive `delta` indicates an outlier.

Pulling it out of the python `for` loop, so numpy
does the looping, gives

```
    delta = np.abs(px_arr - m) - (3 * s + y)
```